VS code terminal stuck in venv when I open specific folders
I setup a virtual env called (tut) using virtualenvwrapper. When I open /Dev/ dir or any of its child dirs in VS code, the terminal adds the env name without brackets to my terminal:
tutusername@usernames-Mac Dev %

However, deactivate command gives permission denied so I thought it was maybe just a UI bug
which pip and which python point to /Users/username/.virtualenvs/tut/bin/pip and /tut/bin/python respectively, instead of my global installs of python/pip, which indicates its 'stuck' in the venv. I can also enter the (tut) env itself, or other envs.
$ workon tut
(tut)tutusername@usernames-Mac Dev %

$ workon env1
(env1)tutusername@usernames-Mac Dev %

What's worse is that if I open for example Documents/ folder, my terminal looks normal
username@usernames-Mac Documents %

I can cd from here into the 'bugged' directory, so the issue seems to be with VS code 'open folder' into /Dev/ and its contents
$ cd Documents/Dev/
username@usernames-Mac Dev %

This issue first happened when I used a terminal macro, while (tut) venv was activated. Which I wrote in ~/.zshrc
alias ch="code . -r"

Aside from this alias, my ~/.zprofile has a few lines related to virtualenvwrapper for setup
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
source /opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Here's what I've tried so far:

delete /tut/ folder

which python & which pip now points to global installations


"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false

no effect



To summarize, my issue is that I cannot open /Dev/ folder in VS code without getting 'stuck' in tut venv. Even now after it doesnt exist.
Why is this happening? How can if be fixed?
